# Log of a Formal Power Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series

Suppose 
$$H(t)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h_nt^n $$
is a formal power series with $h_n$ belonging to a sufficiently nice algebra. I am puzzled by the following. I am reading a paper and the author claims we can take the log of the series
$$ \ln(H(t))$$
and furthermore we can write it as a power series
$$\ln(H(t))=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{P_m}{m}t^m $$
The justification is that we can identify $h_n$ the $n$th complete symmetric functions in a large number of formal variable $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N$. In which case $H(t)$ can be written as
$$H(t)=\prod_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{1-x_it}. $$
Now if you take the log of this product we have 
$$\ln(H(t))=\ln(\prod_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{1-x_it})=-\sum_{i=1}^N \ln(1-x_it) $$
Using the standard power series expansion for $\ln(1-z)$ we obtain 
$$\ln(H(t))=\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_i^kt^k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{P_k}{k}t^k$$
where $P_k=\sum_{j=1}^N x_i^k$ are the normal power sums. It appears that the original claim that 
$$\ln(H(t))=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{P_m}{m}t^m $$
is justified assuming you can actually identify $h_n$ with the $n$th complete symmetric polynomial.

So my question is this: What allows one to identify $h_n$ with  the $n$th complete symmetric polynomial???

Comment: Naively, the $h_n$ recursively determine the elementary symmetric $e_n$, and these in principle determine the $x_i$. But a proper answer has to address the fact that we can't just truncate all these products at some $N$, we've got to make sense of having infinitely many $x_i$. Have you looked into https://global.oup.com/academic/product/symmetric-functions-and-hall-polynomials-9780198504504?cc=gb&lang=en&#